# compare two input field values in a table using angular

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in angularjs and I am trying to make a dynamic table but with custom validations. for instance, I have 2 input fields namely totalSalary and pension paid. The pension paid entered should not be greater than the totalSalary. I am trying to build a custom directive for the pension paid field but how to get the value of the totalSalary field to do the comparison?
Thanks to help.
Ashley
Updated:

This is the table I have made so far as per the next link. [Dynamic table made so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV0rw.jpg)
Below are two fields I need to compare.

```
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.details.salary" fcsa-number required/></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.details.pension" fcsa-number not-greater-than-yearly-sal required/></td>
```

The directive so far I have worked on is as per below. I got the value of pension1 but now how to get the value of salary. On leaving the input for pension1, if the amount is greater than the salary, it should prompt the user and clear the value.

```
angular.module('app').directive("notGreaterThanYearlySal", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
      element.bind('blur', function(event){
        alert(element.val());
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Hello All,Badly need some help for the above. How to get the total salary and if pension is greater than the total salary, to alert the user and clear the input field.

Answer (score 0):

One way you achieve with custom directives

for example  here i match email :

```
  <p>Email:<input type="email" name="email1" ng-model="emailReg">
      Repeat Email:<input type="email" name="email2" ng-model="emailReg2"     ng-match="emailReg"></p>

   <span data-ng-show="myForm.emailReg2.$error.match">Emails have to match!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using  custom Directives :

```
  <button ng-click="add()></button>
 <span ng-show="IsMatch">Emails have to match!</span>

   $scope.add = function() {
  if ($scope.emailReg != $scope.emailReg2) {
   $scope.IsMatch=true;
    return false;
   }
   $scope.IsMatch=false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a really neat way of doing this. You could set something like `ng-max` to the second input and set it's value as the other inputs `ng-model`. Then according to this you could show a error message.

```
<form name="numberForm">
  First input:
  <input type="number" name="number1" ng-model="number1">
  Second input:
  <input type="number" name="number2" ng-model="number2" ng-max="number1">
  <span ng-show="numberForm.number2.$error.max">This field should not be larger than the other</span>
</form>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/dpgfuy06/

Comment: good one @thepio...but what if i am a bad user and wont care about your warnings etc etc??

Comment: Well this will also set the form to be dirty/invalid when the `ng-max` is invalid with the following classes `ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-max`. You can of course deny sending the form or what ever you'd like.

Comment: so we can prevent form submisson uisng this right?.... untill the value is less than first value

Comment: Yes you can. Here's a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/6hmnnLm0/

Answer (score 0):

No need for directive!

Make the following changes in your code:-

Use ng-repeat to iterate over your array of elements in the employee details like this:-

```
 <div ng-repeat ="details in employee.details">
 </div>
```

where all your elements should be put in the employee.details array

Accordingly change your ng-model to "details.pension" and "details.salary"

Make a div below your input fields and specify the condition you want in ng-show

and display an error message for the same.

For instance, in your case it would look like:-

```
<div ng-show="details.pension > details.salary">Pension cannot be greater than salary!
</div>
```

This should do the validations there and then itself.

Answer (score -1):

Using custom directive:

```
     .directive("compareTo", function () {
return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
        otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function (modelValue) {
            return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
        };
        scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function () {
            ngModel.$validate();
        });
    }
};
})
```